# How do I pass the value of a PHP variable?

Tags: 8, javascript

I have the following code in Drupal 6.

```
drupal_add_js(array(
  'take_control_fb' => array(
      //          'pubKey' => variable_get('take_control_public_key', ''),
      'dataUrl' => base_path() . 'admin/build/take_control/fb/getfiles',
      'appUrl' => take_control_app_url(),
      'appDir' => $appDir,
      'extPath' => $extpath,
      'zipMimes' => take_control_zip_mimes(),
      'dirSeparator' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
      'validationString' => $validationString,
      'validationToken' => drupal_get_token($validationString),
      'curUserId' => fileowner(file_directory_path()))), 'setting');
```

I need to convert this, since `drupal_add_js()` is removed from Drupal 8. I can't use this to pass PHP variables to modulename.js file. How can I pass the PHP variable to JavaScript code?

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8 `drupal_add_css()`, `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_library()` have been removed, and we are supposed to use #attached.

```
$page['#attached']['library'][] = 'fluffiness/cuddly-slider';
$page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['fluffiness']['cuddlySlider']['foo'] = 'bar';
```

More details about how JavaScript can be added in Drupal 8 can be found in https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets#configurable-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you simply use the following code.

```
$stream_wrapper_manager = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager');

$form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['take_control_fb'] = [
  'dataUrl' => base_path() . 'admin/build/take_control/fb/getfiles',
  'appUrl' => take_control_app_url(),
  'appDir' => $appDir,
  'extPath' => $extpath,
  'zipMimes' => take_control_zip_mimes(),
  'dirSeparator' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
  'validationString' => $validationString,
  'validationToken' => \Drupal::csrfToken()->get(),
  'curUserId' => fileowner($stream_wrapper_manager->getViaScheme(file_default_scheme())->getDirectoryPath())
];
```

Notice that I also replaced `drupal_get_token()`, which has been replaced from a service, and `file_directory_path()`, which doesn't exist since Drupal 7.

I am assuming your code is used in a form builder; if you use it in another context, replace `$form` with the variable containing the render array.